# FastReport auto wrap the column on next line

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, fastreport

In Fast Report 4.14 I have to create cross-report. Number of columns not defined. When there isn't space on page, columns should be printed on next row, for example:

```
Row 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
Row 2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
Row 3: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Should be printed like

```
Row 1: 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5 
Row 2: 1, 2, 3, 
       4, 5 
Row 3: 1, 2, 3, 
       4, 5
```

I was trying to use TfrxDBCrossView, then vertical bands - doesn't help. When space not enough it moves columns on next page instead of next row. So for the moment I'm adding memos dynamically on MasterBand and change vertical position for it if there is no free space on current line. Is it possible to avoid dynamic generation and use some components? For me will be the best to use TfrxDBCrossView, if it moves columns on next line, not page.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem, I wanted to use the property "wordwrap" at the cell, but just set this property wasn't enough, for the table be correctly generated. So, I set the property `AUTOSIZE = true` to DB_cross and `Wordwrap = true` to to specified cell. The result was which you wanted in your question.

```
Row 1: 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5
```